# SystemError while converting list of RGB tuples into an Image in python

Tags: python, image, tuples, python-imaging-library

I have list of tuples like [(90, 86, 83), (86, 82, 79), (80, 76, 73), (72, 71, 67)]
I want to convert into Image. I have tried some of the methods mentioned previously,but I keep getting the error. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Here is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image
result=[(90, 86, 83), (86, 82, 79), (80, 76, 73), (72, 71, 67)]
h=680, w=230
OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (h,w)
image = Image.new('RGB',OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE)
image.putdata(result)
image.show()
```

Comment: I dont get an error when I run that code although i did move `h` and `w` definitions to their own lines

Comment: I have total 150000 tuples. When I try running with 4, it works fine but for the entire list it gives an error

Comment: I also tried filling the whole image with random RGB tuples, worked fine for me after I moved `h` and `w` to their own lines.  You should be able use a maximum of 680X230 tuples (156400).  I suspect the list you are passing to `image.putdata()` doesn't contain what you think it does.